# How to select a date range *and* the entries immediately before and after that range?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm working with a table where each row has a timestamp, and that timestamp is unique for a given set of other column values:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE time_series (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    category TEXT,
    value INT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON time_series (created, category);

INSERT INTO time_series (created, category, value)
VALUES ('2000-01-01 00:00:00Z', 'foo', 1),
       ('2000-01-01 06:00:00Z', 'bar', 5),
       ('2000-01-01 12:00:00Z', 'bar', 5),
       ('2000-01-02 00:00:00Z', 'bar', 5),
       ('2000-01-02 12:34:45Z', 'bar', 2),
       ('2000-01-03 00:00:00Z', 'bar', 3),
       ('2000-01-04 00:00:00Z', 'bar', 3),
       ('2000-01-04 11:11:11Z', 'foo', 4),
       ('2000-01-04 22:22:22Z', 'bar', 5),
       ('2000-01-04 23:23:23Z', 'bar', 4),
       ('2000-01-05 00:00:00Z', 'foo', 1),
       ('2000-01-05 23:23:23Z', 'bar', 4);
```

The timestamps are not spaced uniformly. My task, given an arbitrary start and end datetime, is to get the entries between those datetimes *and the entries immediately before and after that range.* **Basically, how do I simplify this query:**

```
(SELECT created, value
   FROM time_series
  WHERE category = 'bar'
    AND created < '2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
  ORDER BY created DESC
  LIMIT 1)
 UNION
(SELECT created, value
   FROM time_series
  WHERE category = 'bar'
    AND created >= '2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
    AND created < '2000-01-04 12:00:00Z')
 UNION
(SELECT created, value
   FROM time_series
  WHERE category = 'bar'
    AND created >= '2000-01-04 12:00:00Z'
  ORDER BY created
  LIMIT 1)
 ORDER BY created;

created                 value
2000-01-02 00:00:00+00  5
2000-01-02 12:34:45+00  2
2000-01-03 00:00:00+00  3
2000-01-04 00:00:00+00  3
2000-01-04 22:22:22+00  5
```

The use case is getting the data points to display a graph: I know the datetimes of the left and right edges of the graph, but they will not in general align exactly with `created` datetimes, so in order to display a graph all the way to the edge I need a data point to either side of the range.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=69a34e8dc0f069051a5d72a2cbb12d97)

---

## Non-solutions:

- I can *not* simply select the whole range, because it might be huge.
- I can not select some arbitrarily long period outside of the given range, because that data set might again be huge or whichever period I select might not be enough to get the next readings.

Comment: The definition does not make a lot of sense. All the events within today, after today, and before today is equal to all events. Can you expand?

Comment: @nicooga Not *all*, just the first before and after the range. Hence the word "immediately".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

You can combine `UNION ALL` with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` and some clause bounds.

Something like this:

**APPROACH 1:**

```
SELECT created, 
       value 
  FROM (SELECT created, value
          FROM time_series
         WHERE category = 'bar'
           AND created < '2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
      ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1
       ) AS ub
UNION ALL
      SELECT created, value
        FROM time_series
       WHERE category = 'bar'
         AND created >= '2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
         AND created < '2000-01-04 12:00:00Z'
   UNION ALL
SELECT created, 
       value
 FROM (SELECT created, value 
         FROM time_series
        WHERE category = 'bar'
          AND created >= '2000-01-04 12:00:00Z'
     ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
      ) AS lb 
ORDER BY 1;
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` from approach 1:

```
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=3.60..3.61 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=0.228..0.237 rows=5 loops=1)
   Sort Key: time_series.created
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3.55..3.58 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=0.182..0.195 rows=5 loops=1)
         Group Key: time_series.created, time_series.value
         ->  Append  (cost=1.16..3.53 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=0.073..0.163 rows=5 loops=1)
               ->  Limit  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.070..0.073 rows=1 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.065..0.067 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: time_series.created DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on time_series  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.026..0.035 rows=2 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((created < '2000-01-02 06:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 8
               ->  Seq Scan on time_series time_series_1  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.016 rows=3 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((created >= '2000-01-02 06:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created < '2000-01-04 12:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 7
               ->  Limit  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.051..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.047..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: time_series_2.created
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on time_series time_series_2  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.009..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((created >= '2000-01-04 12:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 8
 Planning time: 0.388 ms
 Execution time: 0.438 ms
(25 rows)
```

Another similar approach can be used.

**APPROACH 2:**

```
  SELECT created, value
        FROM time_series
       WHERE category = 'bar'
         AND created >= (SELECT created
                           FROM time_series
                          WHERE category = 'bar'
                            AND created < '2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
                       ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1)
         AND created < (SELECT created
                          FROM time_series
                         WHERE category = 'bar'
                           AND created >= '2000-01-04 12:00:00Z'
                      ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
                       )
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` from approach 2:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on time_series  (cost=2.33..3.50 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.143..0.157 rows=6 loops=1)
   Filter: ((created >= $0) AND (created < $1) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 4
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.066..0.069 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.061..0.062 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: time_series_1.created
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on time_series time_series_1  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
                       Filter: ((created < '2000-01-02 06:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 8
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.041..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=1.16..1.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: time_series_2.created DESC
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on time_series time_series_2  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.013 rows=2 loops=1)
                       Filter: ((created >= '2000-01-04 12:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (category = 'bar'::text))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 8
 Planning time: 0.392 ms
 Execution time: 0.288 ms
```

As you're using limit, the query will run fast.

**APPROACH 3:**

```
WITH a as (
      SELECT created,
             value, 
             lag(created, 1) OVER (ORDER BY created desc) AS ub,
             lag(created, -1) OVER (ORDER BY created desc) AS lb
        FROM time_series
       WHERE category = 'bar'
 ) SELECT created, 
          value
     FROM a
    WHERE ub>='2000-01-02 06:00:00Z'
      AND lb<'2000-01-04 12:00:00Z'
 ORDER BY created
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` from approach 3:

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=1.19..1.20 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.174..0.181 rows=5 loops=
1)
   Sort Key: a.created
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   CTE a
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1.14..1.16 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.075..0.107 rows=7 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=1.14..1.14 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.056..0.067 rows=7 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: time_series.created DESC
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on time_series  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.018..0.030 rows=7 loops=1)
                       Filter: (category = 'bar'::text)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 3
   ->  CTE Scan on a  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.088..0.131 rows=5 loops=1)
         Filter: ((ub >= '2000-01-02 06:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (lb < '2000-01-04 12:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning time: 0.175 ms
 Execution time: 0.247 ms
(16 rows)
```

Comment: Beat you to it, I'm afraid :) I'm asking how to *simplify* this.

Comment: Approach 2 looks interesting (only one duplicated clause), but `AND created >= (SELECT created` should be `AND created > (SELECT created` to get the same result as the first. Approach 3 gives a different result.

Comment: Approach 3 adjusted with `order by` and some analysis.

Comment: Oh, and approach 2 has `ORDER BY created ASC` and `ORDER BY created DESC` reversed. Found out by adding more records.